# How to install JBPM 6 with MySQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, jbpm

I have downloaded JBPM 6 installer and unzipped it.
I want to use MySQL instead of H2 database. 
I have edited `jbpm-persistence-JPA2.xml` for MySQL and also added `Mysql-Connector.jar`.

But during the demo setup it still uses h2 databse.

please help me on this.

Comment: have you added datasource in standalone.xml? have you added jar for mysql in modules?

Answer (score 0):

please follow this instructions as described [here](https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have change the standalone.xml accordingly, you should add this arguments to the build.xml for jboss server startup.

```
-Dorg.kie.server.persistence.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

-Dorg.kie.server.persistence.ds=java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS
```

"java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS" this can be replace by your JDNI name for your datasource.

Start your Jboss server to see if it works.